# convert a result set with flat column structure into hierarchical data structure

Tags: java, database, data-structures

I have a result of a db query in `java.sql.ResultSet` that needs to be converted to hierarchical data structure. It looks a bit like so:

```
name|version|pname|code|count
n1|1.1|p1|c1|3
n1|1.1|p1|c2|2
n1|1.1|p2|c1|1
n1|1.2|p1|c1|0
n2|1.0|p1|c1|5
```

I need that converted into a hierarchical data structure:

```
N1
 + 1.1
   + p1
     + c1(3)
     + c2(2)
   + p2
     + c1(1)
 + 1.2
    + p1
      + c1(0)
N2
 + 1.0
   + p1
     + c1(5)
```

So my data structure can look something like this

```
Name {
  String name
  List<Version> versions
}

Version {
  String version
  List<PName> pnames
}

PName {
  String pName
  List<CodeCount> codeCounts
}

CodeCount {
  String code
  Integer count
}
```

Anyone have suggestions/code snippets on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways, and how you do it depends on how robust your solution needs to be.

One would be to just write a couple of objects that had the attributes in the database.  Then you could get the result set, and iterate over it, creating a new object each time the key field (for example, "name") changed, and adding it to a list of that object.  Then you'd set the attributes appropriately.  That is the "quick and dirty" solution.

A slightly more robust way would be to use something like Hibernate to do the mapping.

If you do decide to do that, I would also suggest redoing your tables so that they accurately reflect your object structure.  It may not be needed if you just want a fast solution.  But if you are seeking a robust solution for commercial or enterprise software, it's probably a good idea.

Comment: I also need to stream this data out as XML, potentially large amount of data, so that I do not want to store this in memory and do some kind of lazy iteration while writing out the XML.